# What's a shorter word for this type of magic?

Tags: names

I'm having difficulty naming one of the magic types in my conworld. The current name is manipulation magic. However, I'd like to find a shorter word for it, that's 2-4 syllables in length, though preferably 3 syllables if possible. Having a 5-syllable word makes it harder to pronounce (especially for the fictional races of my conworld) as well as not fitting with the names of the other three magic types, which are enhancement magic, perception magic, and creation magic.

Manipulation magic involves performing rituals to attract magical energy, and then using that energy to move non-living objects (similar to telekinesis) and change them (similar to alteration). Splitting it into telekinesis and alteration magic doesn't fit with the rest of my magic system though, nor are they entirely accurate names, so I can't just call it one of those. I haven't been able to find any other potential names besides those two.

Any suggestions that fit the syllable limit and definition would be greatly appreciated.

(If this isn't a question that's allowed to be asked please let me know and I'll remove it.)

Comment: think up a single word to describe your magic then look it up in latin or greek and add "mancy" or "turgy" to the end. example motion magic would be Motomancy or Kiniturgy.

Comment: The question you are asking has no real answer and will form an unlimited set of opinions, which is not allowed on the site. It is difficult to ask objective questions about naming and language, [but it can be and has been done](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/224180/root-words-for-a-portable-communication-device-in-alternate-reality-19th-centur). Consider @John's advice as well. Otherwise this will likely be closed.

Comment: @Rookie_conworlder Let's jump straight to the point ^^ : First and the most simple, please don't accept answers before some time has passed. Indeed, some people are sleeping at the time you wrote your question. Then, know that asking for names is really, really hard to dodge the opinion-based closure stamp. You have to define a strict set of constraints and clear goals. Last question I read was about [finding name particles for names in communication devices](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/224180/80336). 'Might take a look at what issues and solutions to improve your own

Comment: Hi welcome rookie.. alteration.. moving stuff.. to me it all sounds like tentacle magic :p

Comment: *Chirurgy* /'kairɜːdʒɪ/ or perhaps /kai'rɜːdʒɪ/ *could be* Greek for "manipulation". (It really means "working with one's hands". In modern Romance languages it means "surgery".) The word it not used in up-to-date modern English, so it is available; and some English words ending in -urgy denote some type of magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arrangement Magic**

Enhancement, Perception, Creation, and Arrangement magic.

The last school is used to rearrange matter, moving the whole thing or just moving parts relative to each other to change the form.

They all have 3 syllables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This fits all the criteria, including fitting the style of the other names.

Comment: Thank you for the Green Tick. In the future it is recommended to give at least 24 hours before awarding the Tick to give people from the other side of the planet a chance to see the question.

Answer (score 0):

Psionics isnt too wel used or defined (despite attempts to make it so). Among other things it can be about telepathy and psychokinesis. Psychokinesis is essentially telekinesis, but both terms are about more than just levitating stuff, also their manipulation.

So you can use:

- psionics
- psychokinesis
- telekinesis

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Psychokinesis and telekinesis are both 5-syllable words though, and are not what I'm looking for. I also asked for words that fit the definition of my magic type, and psionics is very broad- or not well defined, as you said so yourself. From what I can tell from a Google search, it's an umbrella term to describe psychic abilites. Manipulation magic is not a psychic ability- I'll edit the question post to make that clearer- so psionics wouldn't be an applicable name.

Comment: @rookie_conworlder that was the point: its not well defined, so you can define it. Just like arrangement magic has no definition but the one you give it. Arrangement magic could the telekinesis and modifying materials, but it could also be about landscaping and mostly be used to keep knightly order who speak specific words and want shrubberies off your back.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "Change" magic. It changes the location or morphology of an item.

Or "External" magic; it has external effects like moving or reshaping, where the other types (enhancement, perception, creation) do not really.

Perhaps "Force" magic; it exerts forces on objects, whereas the others do not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Change" magic and "force" magic don't fit the 2-4 syllables requirement. "External" magic does, but it doesn't fit with the style of the names of the other three magic types- the other three can be stated as just nouns (enhancement, perception, creation) while "external" is an adjective.