# Is there any general word for a space between universes?

Tags: magic, science-fiction, universe

I have many imaginary worlds in my head that are all separate from each other and they exist in bubbles but plenty of worlds have enough tech and/or magic (depending on how the individual world works) to visit other worlds.
There's a sort of "space" between these worlds that I call multiverse space but I don't know if there is a word for this concept that others use commonly.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please read our [help] and rework your question to fit our standards: 1 question per port, with enough information to make it answerable

Comment: Hi @ ProtoKirby. when writing your world, you can choose to call one of its component however you want. Some restrictions do rise when you try to fit them with in-world linguistic usages (like [finding root words in specific tongues for a machine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/224180/80336)), but otherwise you're free to call them "*interspaces*", "*Shabazouks*", "*[backrooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Backrooms)*" or "*[astral plane](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Astral_Plane)*" if you wish to. This can be another reason your question was closed (opinion-based closure).

Comment: The trivial answer to your question is "no." The problem is that from a scientific perspective, there is no space between parallel dimensions, universes, etc. I'm a fan of the Dr. Who episode "[Army of Ghosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_Ghosts)" where the space is simply called "the void" and the ship the Daleks use is called a "void ship." Ultimately, @Tortliena is right, because that "space" can be defined anyway you wish (because there is no science behind it), you can name it anything you wish, and thus it violates our no-Qs-about-names policy.

Comment: Unclear why this was closed. Clearly it is answerable, since JBH just did so in the comments (I would upvote it, as an answer). The no names guideline (which I only see a reference to in the meta, with 2 upvotes) is meant to avoid things like "What should I name my horse", i.e., story based. Languages are on-topic, and needing to find out if there is a known name for an obscure thing that your world requires seems explicitly on-topic to my eye, or at any rate, it's splitting hairs that we should even argue about it  rather than just answering it.

Comment: @JamieB I was keeping that card in my hand as I felt it was more "site rules" than worldbuilding learning ^^. Asking directly what other worlds use is not really actively building your own world (and if you plan to copy-paste a name, it's not likely a great idea either). It would be more akin to asking about general culture, like some people asked about real-world history here before.

Comment: Oh, I also didn't notice the history. He did resolve the original close reason.

Comment: What exactly is a "world" in your universe? Is it a place like a planet (or a discworld or something like that), ar a proper universe with lots of planetary systems?
Dependend on this your inter-world-space is either just your version of normal space, or something that exists additionally to it.
Words like the void, the warp, the twisting nether, the dark beyond come to mind.

Comment: **Interstitial Space** in biology is the space between cells. The term should work for the multiverse too, but it's not an accepted term.

Comment: SCP-3001? https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-3001

Answer (score 2):

A space between universes within multiverse is often considered not as a real space, but as a boundary of sorts.
Consider the words:

- border
- edge
- ridge
- veil

Also, since the space between worlds is not a *world* but something else, probably alien and inhospitable to mortal travelers, there are words reflecting such "antiworldness":

- void
- end
- abyss

I don't think there is the one preferred word. The authors tend to choose the word suitable to inflict a certain vibe, for example "the Void" is expected to be rather boring, while "the Abyss" sounds aggressive.

PS I mostly read sci-fi and fantasy in language other than English, but I did my best to summarize, translate and check my findings.